# Change Start Page In ASP.net MVC 3 in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, asp.net

currently i am working on asp.net mvc where by mistake i have right clicked my cshtml file and set it as start page now whenever i run the page it runs with path according to the directory and not in controller way
for example
i have set **views/home/simple.cshtml** as start page now i press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> then it runs in browser as views/home/simple.cshtml
**rather than Home/simple way of controller**

how to **reset this set as start page** in visual studio

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Open up the properties of the project, and click on the web tab. Select the Specific Page radio button. Simply type in the url you want to use!

Or, create a new MVC project and review the properties to see how it is set up as default!

Answer (score 5):

Open the property of project tab "**Web**" then select "**Specific Page**" then click in "SVG Image Maps.".

Don't use the path suggested by visual studio  ex: "`Views/Account/Login.cshtml`".
Use the controller/Action ex: "`Account/Login`".

Or

in "**Web**" select "**CurrentPage**".